# ImportError: No module named 'xgboost'

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, python-import, xgboost

This

```
import sys
from platform import python_version

print(sys.base_prefix)
print(python_version())
```

outputs this:

```
 /home/hp/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow
 3.5.4
```

I tried to install it with the following commands:

```
conda install py-xgboost
```

and

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Each time I am getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'xgboost'
```

OS:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your second attempt should work, your first attempt doesn't look right; as per the [documentation](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/py-xgboost), you should use

```
conda install -c anaconda py-xgboost
```

after you have activated the respective environment where you want the package installed.